# Python ошибка IndexError: index 376 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 376

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте пытаюсь реализовать метод переноса цвета Welsh. Суть в том что на изображение накладывается сетка 15х15 ячеек и в каждой ячейки выберается случайный пиксель. Для этого в окрестности 25х25 вычисляется матожидание и СКО.
На вход подаётся изображение 850х376 пикселей.
Вот получившийся код:

```
sourceimg = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB).astype("float32")
s_height, s_width, r_channels = sourceimg.shape

jitterWidth  = 15
jitterHeight = 15
squareWidth  = 12
squareHeight = 12
# Количество пикселей в ячейке
jitterX = int(s_width / jitterWidth)
jitterY = int(s_height / jitterHeight)

#Подготавливаем данные источника цвета
sourcedata = np.zeros((jitterWidth * jitterHeight, 5))

datacounter = 0
for i in range(jitterWidth):
    randomcoordX  = jitterX * i
    randomcoordXX = jitterX * (i + 1)
    #Проверяем выход за границы
    if randomcoordX  < 0:randomcoordX = 0
    if randomcoordX  > s_width: randomcoordX = s_width-1
    if randomcoordXX < 0:randomcoordXX = 0
    if randomcoordXX > s_width: randomcoordXX = s_width-1
    for j in range(jitterHeight):
        randomcoordY  = jitterY * j
        randomcoordYY = jitterY * (j + 1)

        # Проверяем выход за границы
        if randomcoordY  < 0: randomcoordY = 0
        if randomcoordY  > s_height: randomcoordY = s_height - 1
        if randomcoordYY < 0: randomcoordYY = 0
        if randomcoordYY > s_height: randomcoordYY = s_height - 1

        # Берём случайный пиксель в этой ячейке
        randomX = random.randint(randomcoordX, randomcoordXX)
        randomY = random.randint(randomcoordY, randomcoordYY)

        # Делаем квадрат 25х25 в окрестностях этой точки
        squareCoordX  = randomX - squareWidth
        squareCoordXX = randomX + squareWidth
        squareCoordY  = randomY - squareHeight
        squareCoordYY = randomY + squareHeight

        # Проверяем выход за границы
        if squareCoordX  < 0: squareCoordX = 0
        if squareCoordXX < 0: squareCoordXX = 0
        if squareCoordY  < 0: squareCoordY = 0
        if squareCoordYY < 0: squareCoordYY = 0

        if squareCoordX  >= s_width: squareCoordX = s_width - 1
        if squareCoordXX >= s_width: squareCoordXX = s_width - 1
        if squareCoordY  >= s_height: squareCoordY = s_height - 1
        if squareCoordYY >= s_height: squareCoordYY = s_height - 1

        statdata = np.zeros((jitterX * jitterY))
        # Делаем массив из пикселей в ячейке для вычисления ско и матожидания
        counter = 0
        for x in range(squareCoordX, squareCoordXX):
            for y in range(squareCoordY, squareCoordYY):
                color = sourceimg[x][y][0]
                statdata[counter] = color
                if counter < jitterX * jitterY:
                    counter += 1

        sourcedata[datacounter][0] = sourceimg[randomX][randomY][0]
        sourcedata[datacounter][1] = sourceimg[randomX][randomY][1]
        sourcedata[datacounter][2] = sourceimg[randomX][randomY][2]
        sourcedata[datacounter][3] = statdata.mean()
        sourcedata[datacounter][4] = statdata.std()
        if datacounter < jitterWidth * jitterHeight:
            datacounter += 1
```

Однако в этой строке `color = sourceimg[x][y][0]` получаю ошибку

> IndexError: index 376 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 376.

Как я понял это связано с выходом индекса y за границы. Однако я до этого проверяю выход за границы и этого происходить не должно. Пожалуйста подскажите в чём проблема.

Comment: Если длина списка 376, то номер последнего элемента 375.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась во 2 строке, я перепутал местами ширину и высоту изображения.
Правильный вариант `s_width, s_height, r_channels = sourceimg.shape`